# Adding Tooltips to Phoenix Forms

Tags: css, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a form field:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :title, class: "control-label", "data-tooltip": " Create a new Project" %>
    <%= text_input f, :title, "data-tooltip": " Create a new Project", class: "form-control form-control-title", placeholder: "Your project title" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :title %>
  </div>
```

The working version, with no tooltip, is here:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :title, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :title,  class: "form-control form-control-title", placeholder: "Your project title" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :title %>
  </div>
```

The CSS is setup correctly, because I'm using the tooltip on other elements.

I'm using the same tooltip syntax as a button, which is working:

```
 <%= link("Create Project", to: post_path(@conn, :new), "data-tooltip": " Create a new Project ", "data-placement": "bottom", class: "btn btn-create-project")%>
```

When I hover over the form field, no tooltip shows.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the output of this vs the version that works? Are they identical?

Comment: I added the working version to the OP.

Comment: I meant comparing it with the other version that works with tooltip. The HTML must be different if it works in one place and not in the other.

Comment: It's a bit strange, but could you try instead: `<%= label f, :title, class: "control-label", data: [tooltip: " Create a new Project"] %>`

Comment: As you can see, `label` delegates to [`content_tag`]( https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/master/lib/phoenix_html/form.ex#L1257) and in there, in docs, it explicitly mentions how you should populate [`data` attribute](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#tag/1-data-attributes)

Comment: I tried that Pawel, and it didn't yield any results.